# How do I convert a VMWare file to VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines

I want to take an existing VMWare virtual machine and run it in VirtualBox 2.2+.  Is there any utility to do this?

Answer (score 3):

There's a tutorial on using qemu tools and vditool to do that [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuMagazine/HowTo/Switching_From_VMWare_To_VirtualBox:_.vmdk_To_.vdi_Using_Qemu_+_VdiTool).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a utility as such, but you can load `vmdk` files in VirtualBox, so you can create a guest with your `vmdk` as one disk, a `vdi` as another, then boot up a Linux CD and use `dd` to copy from one to the other.

I don't know if VirtualBox now has support for `vmdk` snapshots. If so, you can use the `vmdk` file as is, without converting to `vdi`, and sacrifice no functionality.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your VMWare virtual machine, install [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com) and do a backup. You will get an image file.
2. Run VirtualBox with the Acronis Recovery iso. Restore from previously created image.

Acronis isn't free though.